# Nested data items from multiple API calls returning undefined in React component

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api

I have a pair of functions that recursively call Microsoft's Graph API to build out the folder structure of an Outlook inbox:

```
export async function getParentFolders(accessToken){
  const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

  const folders = await client
                .api('me/mailFolders?$top=100')
                .select('displayName,id,childFolderCount')
                .get();

  const parentFolders = await folders.value.reduce((acc, next)=>{
    let obj = {};
    obj['displayName'] = next.displayName;
    obj['id'] = next.id;
    obj['childFolderCount'] = next.childFolderCount;

    acc.push(obj);

    return acc;
  },[]);

  return parentFolders;}

export async function getChildFolders(accessToken, parents){
  const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

  if(Array.isArray(parents) && parents.length > 0){
    parents.map( async (p) => {
        if(p.childFolderCount > 0){
            
            const children = await client
                            .api(`me/mailFolders/${p.id}/childFolders`)
                            .select('displayName,id,childFolderCount')
                            .get();

            p['subfolders'] = children.value;

            getChildFolders(accessToken, children.value);
            
        }
    })
}

  return parents}
```

They seem to work great, but when I try to render the structure in a component, only the top level (parent folders) render, when I try to console log the subfolder elements, I get undefined.

In the React Component tools, I can see the complete data (w/ subfolders) in props which leads me to think its an async issue, but in the parent component I am using await to wait for all calls to return before setting the "folders" state, and I am using a completeData state check that has to be set to true before the child component renders. Any thoughts??

Parent component:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './Context'
import { getMessages, getParentFolders, getChildFolders } from './GraphService';
import FolderTree from './FolderTree'
import {Client} from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client'

const Mailbox = () => {

    const { user, token } = useContext(AppContext);
    const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);
    const [completeData, setCompleteData] = useState(false)

    const getFolderStructure = async ()=>{
        let parents = await getParentFolders(token);
        let parentsWithChildren = await getChildFolders(token, parents);

        setFolders(parentsWithChildren);

    };

    useEffect(()=>{

        getFolderStructure();

    },[token]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        // Check if all APIs have completed and returned full folder structure
        if(folders.every(f => !f.subfolders)){
            setCompleteData(true)
        }
    
    },[folders])


return (
    <div>
        {completeData ? <FolderTree folders={folders} />: null}
    </div>)
}

export default Mailbox;
```

Child component (getting undefined for subfolders):

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
      height: 110,
      flexGrow: 1,
      maxWidth: 400,
    },
  });

 const FolderTree = ( { folders } ) =>{
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  return data.map(item => (
    <React.Fragment key={item.displayName}>
      <div>{item.displayName}</div>
      
      {/* {(item.childFolderCount !== 0 && item.subfolders.length !== 0) ? <Free items={item.subfolders} />: null} */}
      {item.childFolderCount > 0 ? console.log(item.subfolders): null}
      
    </React.Fragment>
  ))
}


export default FolderTree;
```

Comment: I would try these MS Graph API calls in MS Graph Explorer or POSTMAN or write a simple Graph API application and see if it works. This way you can isolate the issue and look at whatelse is failing..